# How can I disable a constraint?

Tags: sql-server-2005, constraints

I have a constraint (named `INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS_PK`) in my SQL Server 2005 table.

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ALTER TABLE INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS NOCHECK CONSTRAINT INVS_ITEM_LOCATIONS_PK

Comment: I tried it but it seems it is not allowed for primary keys. Based on the naming convention I assume this constraint is indeed for a PK.  TW, I get the following error: "Object 'my_pk' cannot be disabled or enabled. This action applies only to foreign key and check constraints."

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you can DISABLE a constraint, maybe you need to DROP the constraint?